# Post email replies to the Google Group

Tags: email, google-workspace, google-groups

I have a Google Business subscription for a custom domain. I want to use Google groups to collaborate the emails for a particular purpose. For example I want the Google Group to manage all the job applications.
I have setup a Group named as `HR` and set the posting authorization to public. Now anyone can post to the email `hr@domain.com`

The problem is the Group members (HR guys of my company) have to go to the group to post reply to the candidate. If they do it by replying the email, the reply gets directly to the candidate and doesn't get posted to the group at all.

There're more than one HR guy who'll be tracking the candidate. So if the replies are posted directly to the candidate another HR won't be able to tell if the candidate have been taken care of.

So in short, what I want is the email reply should post a reply on the candidate's original post in the group so that the user can get the reply as well as the reply gets posted on the group for the records.

Is it possible to do or not and if yes, how can I do that?

Comment: I hope the situation is clear. If not, please ask in comment and I'll add more details. Thanks

Comment: If the HR department is also using gmail, can you add "Reply-to: hr@domain.com" and/or add hr@domain.com as a 2nd address that they can post from? Of course, they'll still have to remember to use that address when replying. A third possibility would be have to them just login as hr@domain.com when answering/sending email?

Comment: @barrycarter Actually the hr@domain.com email doesn't exists. The HR guys have their own email ids on the domain. The hr@domain.com email will post the candidate's application to the group, informing the group members that someone applied for some post. They can just ask for more info or schedule the interview by replying. The problem was the reply doesn't get posted on the group, thus more than one HR replies to the same guy which looks awkward. We've asked HR guys to post on group to reply, but that's just too much work to login to the the group separately.

Comment: Instead of having hr@domain.com being a forward, could you turn it into a single account where any HR person could login (shared passwords are a bad idea, but perhaps OK here) and thus see all the received and sent mail to/from that account? Or is that what HR is objecting to?

Comment: That would cost us another account (Google apps charges for per account). Apart from that we won't be able to know which HR posted reply.

Comment: So, something like a filter: when someone in HR sends an email, a copy is automatically sent to everyone in HR? For my original idea, you could use a templated sig file and train HR to put their name in a specific place in the template when answering.

Comment: Actually we were having a better solution by using alias and giving alias access to every HR. But that was too unorganized. Google Groups are way better in organizing candidate and they are working a lot. We do post about candidate results/feedback on the group(obviously not sending the post as email to the candidate). We definitely want to use Groups instead of individual emails. This issue is not that big to change strategies, but it's still an issue which needs to be solved. I hope you understood the concern.